# Sorting a data files rows by some crieteria from each row

Tags: c#, file

I have a tab delimited file like this:

```
Name    ID    LastName    ZipCode     Age    Address    SomeOtherColumn   AnotherColumn 
Yo      122   YoYo        123          56     Main St   3847387           efhhsvhfv
Joe     145   Klose        444         34     Main St   45787              8u8u78
Yo      122   YoYo        456          56     5th Ave    ttytty4AA         4rt8r78t
Mary    862   Mary        478          22     Roe Ave    r876aa234         trfrtrt
```

I want to sort the rows of this file with combination of `Name + ID + LastName` so for example all "Yo" guy rows will now be together and not scattered through the whole file, etc...

It has many rows, around 120,000 rows.  I was looking for some ideas and algorithms on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ, for example:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path")
    .Skip(1) // header
    .Select(Line => new { Line, Fields = Line.Split('\t') })
    .Where(x => x.Fields.Length == 8)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Line,
        x.Fields,
        Name = x.Fields[0],
        ID = x.Fields[1],
        LastName = x.Fields[2],
        ZipCode = x.Fields[3],
        Age = x.Fields[4],
        Address = x.Fields[5],
        SomeOtherColumn = x.Fields[6],
        AnotherColumn = x.Fields[7]
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ID)
    .ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
    .Select(x => x.Line);
```

Things to note:

- you should use an available CSV parser to parse the csv-file
- you should use a real class with those properties instead of the anonymous type
- then use a `List<ThisType>` instead of the strings to process it further

Comment: what is '.Where(x => x.Fields.Length == 8)
' for?

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack: to skip invalid data, for example empty lines

Comment: Thanks, what is "•you should use a real class with those properties instead of the anonymous type" ?  Can you show a sample class that you mean?

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack: just a simple class with all those properties, i would also recommend to use the real type instead of always `string`, for example `int` for the `Age`. You need to parse the field with `int.Parse`/`int.TryParse`(to validate). You just need to replace the initialization of the anonymous type with `new NameOfClass { Line = x.Line, Fields = x.Fields, ...}` in the `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Skip(1) //column names
            .Select(line => new { line = line, parts = line.Split('\t') })
            .OrderBy(x => x.parts[0]) //name
            .ThenBy(x => x.parts[2])  //lastname
            .ThenBy(x => x.parts[1])  //id
            .Select(x => x.line);

File.WriteAllLines(newfilename, query);
```